# Python 2.7 Trouble With Printing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a program that will convert digital storage units. Like, you could ask it how many bits are in x amount of megabits. I'm just testing it with one if statement, but I CANNOT get it to print the answer.

```
import re

UNITS = ["bit", "byte", "exabit", "exabyte", "gigabit", "gigabyte", 
"kilobit", "kilobyte", "megabit", "megabyte", "petabit", "petabyte", 
"terabit", "terabyte"]

PLURAL_UNITS = ["bits", "bytes", "exabits", "exabytes", "gigabits", 
"gigabytes", "kilobits", "kilobytes", "megabits", "megabytes", "petabits", 
"petabytes", "terabits", "terabytes"]

PROMPT_1 = "How many "
PROMPT_2 = "are in "

def convert():
    first_unit = raw_input(PROMPT_1)
    second_unit = raw_input(PROMPT_2)

    number_of = re.findall('\d+', second_unit)

    number = number_of[0]

    if first_unit == PLURAL_UNITS[0] and second_unit == " " + PLURAL_UNITS[1]:
        answer = float(number)*8
        print(answer)


convert()
```

Comment: What exactly happens, and how does it differ from your expected result?

Comment: Are you adding a space to your second raw input? Because that is what you are checking for

Comment: @stybl I expect it to print the answer, but it just skips to the command line prompt in the IDLE shell.

Comment: @marsh Yes, because when you enter it, you enter it as "500 bytes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't print because it doesn't reach your `print` statement. One or both of your conditions of your `if` statement is `False`. To check which, print their results:

```
def convert():
    first_unit = raw_input(PROMPT_1)
    second_unit = raw_input(PROMPT_2)

    number_of = re.findall('\d+', second_unit)

    number = number_of[0]

    print('first check:', first_unit == PLURAL_UNITS[0])
    print('second check:', second_unit == " " + PLURAL_UNITS[1])
    if first_unit == PLURAL_UNITS[0] and second_unit == " " + PLURAL_UNITS[1]:
        answer = float(number)*8
        print(answer)


convert()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
if first_unit == PLURAL_UNITS[0] and second_unit == " " + PLURAL_UNITS[1]:
```

With this line your code will only print if the first input is `"bits"` and the second input is `" bytes"`. Inputting anything else makes the code under the if statement (which includes your `print`) get skipped.

Comment: When I test it, I enter it so that it works with [0] and [1]

Comment: @OwenStrand Yes but the if statement looks for the exact input `" bytes"`. That is, a space followed by the word bytes. Adding a number (i.e. "1024 bytes") makes it false.

Answer (score -2):

In python2, print is a statement, not a function.
print answer

Comment: In this case, this should not be what is causing the problem. `print()` works fine in python2 under certain conditions. As it will just be evaluated as `print ()`

Comment: When you print a single object `x`, `print(x)` and `print x` work *exactly* the same in Python 2.